# Why do I get a runtime error with two linked gtk toggle buttons?

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, signals, togglebutton

I have two toggle buttons that I want to link together so that pressing one releases the other one. So my signals look like this

```
def on_btn1_tgl_clicked(self, widget, data=None):
    toggled = not self.btn2_toggle.get_active()
    self.btn2_toggle.set_active(toggled)

def on_btn2_tgl_clicked(self, widget, data=None):
    toggled = not self.btn1_toggle.get_active()
    self.btn1_toggle.set_active(toggled)
```

This seems to work just as I expect, except that when I run the code I get this error

> Error in sys.excepthook:
>
> RuntimeError
>
> Original exception was:
>
> RuntimeError

The buttons work fine and nothing crashes, but I don't know why I'm getting the error, or what it means. If I don't link the buttons I don't get any errors.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: When I run your code, I get this exception : `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded` (and the buttons doesn't work). My explication is : When you click on button 1, it emit the "toggled" signal and execute your `on_btn1_tgl_clicked()` method. In this method, you use `gtk.ToggleButton.set_active()` which emit a toggled signal that call your `on_btn2_tg1_clicked()` method which emit also a toggled signal. So, we enter in infinite loop. That's why the exception is raised.

Comment: @LoïcGRENON I was afraid of that. I originally had it use the "toggled" signal, but I thought that would produce this recursion effect, so I changed it to the "clicked" signal. From [the documentation I'm looking at](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkbutton.html#signal-gtkbutton--clicked), it sounds like that signal would only be emitted by user action. But I guess not. Do you have any ideas on how to set up paired buttons? I'm assuming there must be some way.

Comment: @LoïcGRENON Okay. Well, you answered my question, so if you want to put your comment as an answer, I'll mark it correct. Maybe I'll start another question about how to actually link the two buttons.

Comment: I'm assuming there must be some way too, but I don't see how. It's possible with `gtk.RadioButton` because it have a `set_group` method but `gtk.ToggleButton` doesn't have.

Comment: The way to do it is blocking the signal handler before calling *toggle.set_active*, and releasing it after. There functions in GLib for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I run your code, I get this exception :

`RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded` and the buttons doesn't work.

My explication is :

1. When you click on button 1, it emit the `toggled` signal and execute your `on_btn1_tgl_clicked()` method.
2. In this method, you use `gtk.ToggleButton.set_active()` which emit a `toggled` signal too that call your `on_btn2_tg1_clicked()` method which emit also a `toggled` signal.

   So, we enter in infinite loop. That's why the exception is raised.

Answer (score 1):

Just check before you set the button's state, whether it already has the state you are setting it to.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to change the state of button every time it is changed by user? If you want to prevent user from changing, use `widget.set_sensitive(False)`. Or if you want to prevent changing state based on some conditions, I think you can return `True` in `on_btn1_tgl_clicked` to say GTK "I already handled this event, so you dont handle it yourself", and GTK will not change its state. If you return `False` or nothing, GTK will handle it and changes its state.

Comment: I want to change the state of the other button everytime the first one is changed by the user.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this by setting the second button to the opposite of the first one, instead of the opposite of its current state. So something like

```
def on_btn1_tgl_clicked(self, widget, data=None):
    toggle_val = self.btn1_toggle.get_active()
    self.btn2_toggle.set_active(not toggle_val)

def on_btn2_tgl_clicked(self, widget, data=None):
    toggle_val = self.btn2_toggle.get_active()
    self.btn1_toggle.set_active(not toggle_val)
```

This doesn't seem to suffer from the recursion problems of the other solution.